# full calendar to display current week and next week

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar to display the my events at the moment i have the default view at displaying the last week and current week, however i want the user to display to only see this week and next week in the calendar 
Below i have attached my code.

```html
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         views: {
            agendaWeek: {
                type: 'agenda',
                duration: {weeks: 3},
                rows: 2
            }
        },
  header: {
   left: '',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'agendaWeek'
  },
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: true,
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                 minTime: '13:00:00', /* calendar start Timing */
        maxTime: '24:00:00',  /* calendar end Timing */
                
                
  eventLimit: true,
        events: "load_Emp_Roster.php",
        displayEventTime: true,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }
        },
       selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
       select: function (start, end, allDay) {
      
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }, 
        
    

    });
});

function displayMessage(message) {
     $(".response").html("<div align='center' style='padding:20px;font-size:18px;color:#3539EA' class='success'>"+message+"</div>");
    setInterval(function() { $(".success").fadeOut(); }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange

I would add something like this (please note, I haven't tested this):

```
visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
  return {
    start: currentDate.clone(),
    end: currentDate.clone().add(2, 'weeks')
  };
}
```